# php regular expression plus sign

Tags: php, regex

I'm playing around with PHP Regex in order to improve my skills with it.

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the plus sign - so I wrote the following code:

```
$subject = 'aaa bbb cccc dddd';
echo preg_replace('/(\w)/',"$1*",$subject) . '<br>';
echo preg_replace('/(\w+)/',"$1*",$subject) . '<br>';
echo preg_replace('/(\w)+/',"$1*",$subject) . '<br>';
```

With results in:

```
a*a*a* b*b*b* c*c*c*c* d*d*d*d*
aaa* bbb* cccc* dddd*
a* b* c* d*
```

I don't understand why these results come about. Can someone please explain what's going on in this example

Comment: @NeverHopeless, what's with the new tag?  Please explain why you're *replacing* both the `regex` and `php` tags with it.

Comment: @Charles, I have experienced the regex problem asked by users mostly belongs to either PHP and ASP.Net to validate user input or parse xml/json responses and some times people just mention `regex` tag without specifying programming language. So its a combined representation of two entities and help to represent both things at once. I won't create combine tags other than these two since they are frequently used.

Comment: @NeverHopeless one of the goals of having tags is allowing categorization of questions.  The SO community has decided that *all* regex questions belong under the `regex` tag.  Creating an isolated island *just* for PHP regex questions is completely inappropriate because it *hurts question categorization*.  It's perfectly fine to just include the language tag when it matters.  *Most* regexes in use follow either the POSIX or Perl standards, so much of the time the actual regex syntax / environment doesn't matter too much regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in regular expressions, `+` means `one or more of the preceding character or group`.

The pattern `/(\w)/`, means match a single word character (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) in a single group. So it will match each letter. The first match group will be just `a`. The replace will replace each individual letter with that letter followed by an asterisk.

The pattern `/(\w+)/` will match one or more word characters in a group. So it will match each block of letters. The first match group will be `aaa`. The replace will replace each block of multiple letters followed by a asterisk.

The last pattern `/(\w)+/` is a little more tricky, but will match a single word character in a group but the `+` means that it will match one or more of the group. So the first match will be `a`, but the replace will replace all of the groups until there isn't a match with the last matched group (of course followed by an asterisk). So if you tried the string `aaab ccc`, your result would end up as `b* c*`. `b` is the last matched group in the first sequence and so the replace would use that.

Comment: I still don't understand the last one. let's say we have $subject = "abc def" which will result in "c* f*" so... 6 groups are matched {"a","b","c","d","e","f"} now your are saying that a* should be returned but is overwritten by b* which is overwritten by c*- and the same process for the other three ? why?

Comment: The `+` outside the group means to match one or more groups. Once it doesn't match (the space or end of string), the replace will replace all matched groups with the last matched group. So the 3 groups found in `abc` will be replaced with the last match which was `c`.

Comment: Another explanation: The regex engine will match from left to right one character at a time. It will start with the first part of the expression which is `(\w)`. `a`, match and engine will continue. It will find `b`, match and continue. It will find `c`, match and continue. It will find space and not match. Then it will expand the expression to include the + which will match `abc`. The expression ends and so it will look for a replace. `$1` will be equal to `c` as that was the last matched group and it will replace all that it has matched so far `abc`. Then continues on the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake isn't the plus sign, it's understanding what the parentesis is for and how it works.  The parenthesis is for grouping your match into a variable, hence why you can do $1, the second set of () gives you $2 and so on...

- (\w) means 1 word character
- (\w+) means 1 or more word characters
- (\w)+ matches 1 or more word characters, but only the first one is put into the variable, because only the \w is inside the paranthesis